# Why isnt this java code working? simple calculator

Tags: java

This is a calculator for simple arithmetic operations where only + and - is used. The logic part is pretty easy, but I am embarrassed to say the code is not working. The input is with unknown digits. eg : "4/2" or "42+34" should both should be acceptable. I am not so comfortable with strings and their functions, so please help out. Thank you! :)

```
/*
 *Calculator with only + and - 
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator {
    public static String strng;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.Calculator();
    }

    public void Calculator()
    {
        int op1=0,op2=0,flag=0,index=0;
        String Operator=null;
        System.out.println("java calculator");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        strng= sc.nextLine();

        if(strng.indexOf("+")>0) {
            Operator = "+";
            index=strng.indexOf("+");
            if(strng.lastIndexOf("+")!=index){
              Operator="++";
              flag=1;
            }
        }
        else if(strng.indexOf("-")>0) {
            Operator="-";
            index=strng.indexOf("-");
            if(strng.lastIndexOf("-")!=index){
              Operator="--";
              flag=1;
            }
        } else if(strng.indexOf("*")>0) {
            Operator="*";
            index=strng.indexOf("*");
        } else if(strng.indexOf("/")>0) {
            Operator="/";
            index=strng.indexOf("/");
        } 

        if((index>0)&&(flag==0)) {
           op1=Integer.parseInt(strng.substring(0,index-1));
           op2=Integer.parseInt(strng.substring(index+1));
           Operation(Operator,op1,op2);
        }

        if(flag==1) {
           op1=Integer.parseInt(strng.substring(0,index-1));
           op2=Integer.parseInt(strng.substring(index+2)); 
           Operation(Operator,op1,op2);
        } else { //to separate the operator and operands string functions.
           System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
     }  


     public void Operation(String Operator, int operand1, int operand2) {
        if(Operator.equals("+")){ Add(operand1,operand2); }
        if(Operator.equals("-")){ Subtract(operand1,operand2); }
        if(Operator.equals("*")){ Multiply(operand1,operand2); }
        if(Operator.equals("/")){ Divide(operand1,operand2); }
        if(Operator.equals("++")){ Increment(operand1); }
        if(Operator.equals("--")){
            Decrement(operand1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
        }
    } 


    void Add(int op1, int op2) {
        System.out.println(strng+"="+(op1+op2));
    }

    void Subtract(int op1, int op2) {
        System.out.println(strng+"="+(op1-op2));
    }  

    void Increment(int op1) {
        System.out.println(strng+"="+(op1+1));
    }

    void Decrement(int op1) {
        System.out.println(strng+"="+(op1-1));
    }

    void Multiply(int op1, int op2) {
        int ans=0;
        int  x = op1<op2?op1:op2;
        int y = op1>op2?op1:op2;
        for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){
            ans=ans+y;
        } 
        System.out.println(strng+"="+ans);
    }

    void Divide(int op1, int op2) {
        int count=0,rem=op1;

        while(rem>=op2){
            rem=rem-op2;
            count=count+1;
        } 
        System.out.println(strng+"="+count); //return rem for modulo operand
    }

}
```

Comment: Please narrow down your issue.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag!

Comment: How is it not working?  When you step through the code in a debugger, at what point does the observed behavior deviate from expected behavior?

Comment: I am sorry but i wasnt able to figure out where the problem was.
When run, the program just built and there was no o/p at all which is why i posted the whole code.
and it aint homework. practice only.

Comment: Respect Java naming conventions and use lowerCamelCase for methods. Same for variable names

Comment: I ran your class, no problem. It showed the prompt "java calculator" and accepted input. Only then it failed, with different errors for different inputs -- so there's definitely something going on there, just wrong.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik
that must be because i haven't handled the exceptions properly as I am not very clear about that topic...
And i used tokeniser later to make the sorting easier and smaller...I am afraid i compensate with the increment and decrement options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not comfortable with the way you're looking for the symbols in the string.  I would advise that you look into [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), which will allow you to split your symbols and your numerals.

Comment: but could you pinpoint the problem here anyways please so i dont repeat it further..I am afraid my basics are not very clear. ^.^'

Comment: @Suzuka:  It is, in part, how you're splitting up your strings to perform operations on them (a substring goes from [0, n), and you're assuming that you've got the nth character when you perform your next substring).  Using `String.split()` where appropriate would help tons.

Answer (score -2):

You are calling a constructor right ... Constructor doesnt support void..  Hope that helps

Comment: No...that's an actual method call.  I don't see a [custom] constructor being declared/called anywhere else.

Comment: @Suzuka You are not right to name a method using CamelCase. This is against the very strong convention in Java to use lowerCamelCase for method names -- see how you managed to confuse elsa.